# Консольные приложения и их возможности

Tags: c++, консоль

Изучения языка программирования начинается с консольных программ. Могут ли консольные программы применять в реальной жизни? Какого возможности консольных программ, например, на С++? Какая есть консольная программа, которая используется многими?

Comment: Консольные программы используются для изучения языка и реализации на них алгоритмов, так как это самая простая среда разработки, не требующая установки других пакетов.

Comment: Ну сами консольные программы используются кем-то или только для изучения языка?

Comment: Они могут использоваться там, где не требуется интерактивное взаимодействие с неподготовленным пользователем. Например, консольными программами могут служить различные утилиты.

Comment: А можно пример популярной консольной программы?

Comment: Компилятор С++.

Comment: @Developer  Например, это может быть валидатор XML файла, любая служеюнач утилита, как, например, дефрагментация диска и т.д.

Comment: Far знаете? :) Откровенно говоря, у меня, например, если есть возможность одно и то же дело выполнить в консоли и в графике - я предпочту консоль. Даже программы в основном пишу в редакторе FTE, а компилирую в командной строке...

Comment: А как насчёт vim'а? Или он недостаточно консольный?

Comment: @Harry, far - это windows-приложение вообще-то уже давно. Он не совсем консольный.

Comment: @Qwertiy Это точно не GUI :) Не знаю, я отличаю термины *консольное* приложение и *приложение командной строки*...

Comment: Конечные пользователи, разумеется, вряд ли захотят работать с консольной программой. Если уж программа имеет UI, на сегодняшний день он должен быть графическим. Но вот всякие утилиты для программистов вполне могут быть консольными, довольно часто программисты предпочитают именно консольные программы. Так что выбирайте вашу целевую группу.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что back-end чуть меньше, чем весь, живет в консоле.

Comment: @isnullxbh: а зачем ему консоль? Он живёт в виде библиотеки и вообще не обладаем интерфейсом, ни графическим, ни консольным.

Comment: @VladD, он - это кто ? Сервер ? Сервер живет в виде библиотеки ?)

Comment: @isnullxbh: Если это сервер, то он — процесс без UI, в частности, без консоли. Зачем она ему?

Comment: @VladD, прозвучит банально, но запускаете Вы его как ? Может я чего-то не знаю, если так - то буду рад "обновить" свои знания.

Comment: @isnullxbh: А как вы запускаете любое приложение? Ну как угодно: через командную строку, через реестр (HKLM/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run), через даблклик по приложению в файл-менеджере, из другого процесса при помощи CreateProcess...

Comment: @VladD, понял Вас, спасибо, дошло )))

Answer (score 3):

1. Консольные приложения используются на серверах. Там даже может быть не запущен графический интерфейс.
2. Консольные приложения, в отличие от графических, можно использовать по ssh-соединению.
3. Их можно использовать как шаги автоматизации - надо лишь написать команду в батнике и не надо заполнять пачку полей руками.
4. REPL-среды языков программирования вполне могут быть консольными.
5. Почти все компиляторы консольные, чтобы один и тот же компилятор можно было использовать в связке с различными IDE.

И ещё куча всего, что сразу и не вспомнил.

Answer (score 1):

Да,могут, но сейчас больше распространены программы с использованием GUI.
 Возможности по сравнению с программой с интерфейсом почти одинаковые, но они менее удобны для использования. Консольные приложения главным образом используются для выполнения вторичных или фоновых задач.